Continued fraction of irrational number and periodicity
Theorem: Let $\xi$ be irrational. Its continued fraction $\xi = [a_0, a_1, \ldots]$ is periodic from a certain point, if and only if $\xi$ is an algebraic number of degree 2 (i.e., an irrational root of some quadratic polynomial with integer coefficients).
Now I have a trouble with proving the second implication: Let $\xi$ satisfy $a \xi^2 + b \xi + c = 0$ for some $a, b, c \in \mathbb{Z}, a \neq 0$.
Substituting here expression for $\xi$ from another Theorem, we get a quadratic equation $A_n \xi_{n+1}^{2} + B_n \xi_{n+1} + C_n = 0$, where $A_n = a p_n^2 + b p_n q_n + c q_n^2$, $B_n = 2a p_n p_{n-1} + b p_n q_{n-1} + b p_{n-1} q_n +2c q_n q_{n-1}$, $C_n = p_{n-1}^2a + p_{n-1} q_{n-1}b + c q_{n-1}^2$
Then it can be shown that there exists $K \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $-K < A_n, B_n, C_n < K$ for all $n$.
And here I really don't know what to do with it - how can someone prove that such a K exist if we don't know that the continued fraction is periodic and the sequences {${p_n}$} and {$q_n$} are increasing?
Remark:
The fraction $\frac{p_n}{q_n}$ (for $n \geq 0$) is the $n$-th convergent of the number $\xi$ and the following recurrence relations hold:
$p_{-1} = 1, p_0 = a_0, p_{n+1} = a_{n+1}p_n + p_{n-1}$,
$q_{-1} = 0, \, q_0 = 1, \, q_{n+1} = a_{n+1}q_n + q_{n-1}$

Will Pell's equation help?

I am sorry but I can't see how exactly it could be helpful

It shows the continued fraction for $\sqrt n$ when $n$ is a non-square positive integer is periodic.

I have it, thank you
